# Difference between a for loop and for while nested with list()

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop

Can someone tell me what the difference between these two loops / code snippets are?

I am getting the same output, but a text book is indicating  there is a difference with the outer and inner loop?  Any clarification would be helpful.  I don't think I am understanding the list with each function.

Array definition:

```
$newArray  = array(array('CODE' => 'TIR', 'Description' =>'TIRES', 'Price' => 100),
                   array('CODE' => 'OIL', 'Description' => 'Oil', 'Price' =>10),
                   array('CODE' => 'SPK', 'Description' => 'Spark Plug', 'Price' =>40)
             );
```

Code snippet 1:

```
for ($row = 0; $row < 3; $row ++)
{           
    echo ' |'.$newArray[$row]['CODE'].'| '.$newArray[$row]['Description']. '| '.$newArray[$row]['Price'];
    echo  '<br />';
    echo  '<br />';      
}
```

Code snippet 2:

```
for ($row =0; $row <3; $row ++)
{
    while (list($key, $value) = each ($newArray[$row]))
    {
        echo "|$value";
    }
    echo  '<br />';
    echo  '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Well, once you hardcode the second dimension keys and in the second one you use a while loop to loop through all elements of each subArray. Just add another value to each subArray and you will see it, something like: `"another element" => "Will only be shown by the second code snippet"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's a difference if you look at it from algorithm point of view.

The first one has the time complexity of O(n) and the second one O(n<sup>2</sup>).

So, the first one is more efficient.

Comment: The two code snippets do net the same ting, so you can't really compare them.

Comment: Well you are assuming that the second dimension is hardcoded, I am assuming both array length and dimension to be variable.